# MOSS - Event ID 5785 repeats every 5 min in the Event Viewer

Tags: 2007

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Office SharePoint Server
Event Category: Publishing Cache 
Event ID:   5785
Date:       7/30/2013
Time:       4:38:10 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   MSMOSSWEB1
Description:
Unable to connect publishing custom string handler for output caching.  IIS Instance Id is '1458748636', Url is ' site name and _layouts/images/filter.gif'.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

There are many more with different errors but same event ID

I am on MOSS June 2011CU,does anybody know anything about this , this error is right from the morning till evening and keeps coming every 2-5 min i am afraid this will fill up the logs and the machine might run low on space

Please advice.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution is to modify the web.config. I haven't tested, ymmv, be sure to make a copy of your web.config before starting, etc.

http://vettekerry.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/fix-the-annoying-event-id-5785/

> The solution is to modify the web.config of the application. Remove
>   the PublishingHttpModule module that was added by the root web.config:
>
> ```
> <httpModules>
>
>    <remove name=”PublishingHttpModule” />
>
> </httpModules>
> ```

Comment: This can be caused when you add an Application in the IIS web site for that SharePoint Web Application. Or maybe you converted either the '_layouts' or '_layouts/images' Virtual Directory to an application. If either is the case, you can remove the **PublishingHttpModule** from the child application's web.config. Don't remove it from the IIS site root web.config.

Comment: Steven no changes has been done recently one of the webserver was down and it was brought back on it seemed to be some hardware issue but its been happening ever since and on the Eventviewer the error has still not stopped since yestrerday and everytime its different error with same event idIIS Instance Id is '1458748636', Url is 'http://..../_layouts/images/titlegraphic.gif' and then the next error would say IIS Instance Id is '1458748636', Url is 'http://...../_layouts/images/viewheadergrad.gif and it continues with different url